# Apache Cordova Visual Studio 2015 external webview controled by app

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, cordova, native

I am making a web application for some website and I need to control this site with in app buttons.

I have tried for example Cordova InAppBrowser which allows you to execute script or inject css but can not display my own buttons in app. What is a best solution for this situaltion please.

**Example of app:**

[image: Example of mobile app]

Thank you a lot for your advices.

Jakub Kučera